# Access to option data in lightning combobox?

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-combobox

Given this code:

HTML :

```
<lightning-combobox name='Test' label='Testing' placeholder={serviceReopenTest}
           options={serviceOption} onchange={handleServiceChange} value={idServiceOption} required>
</lightning-combobox>
```

JS:

```
handleServiceChange(event) {
        this.idService= event.detail.value;
}
```

In this moment, I have the id of service stored in **idService** var, because **event.detail.value** has the ID data. The problem is that I need text data of the **{serviceOption}**. For example, **{serviceOption}** is a picklist with 2 options: 'A' and 'B'. I need that, when user picks 'A', pass the String 'A' (not only the ID) to the JS, but I don't know how to access to the **options** data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sotring your data in the `serviceOption` property, you can easily get the text using the value from `idServiceOption` which you are already getting.

1 way to do it is using the find method:

```
serviceOption.find( opt => opt.value === event.detail.value)
```

you can then access the text from the fetched value.

Comment: Worked! Actually, is a solution that I thought, but I wanted to know if there is any direct way to access to these data, without the requirement of using find. Thanks!